# Fixed right navigation bar moves with much text

Tags: html, css

I've created a navigation list with plain and simple HTML and some CSS. It should be on the right side of the page and shouldn't move neither if there is a lot of content on the page nor if the user scrolls down.

After I added some sample text to my website I recognized that the navigation element is more in the left side. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

This is the first minimal example with just some text:

https://jsfiddle.net/sck6nL6w/2/

And a snippet with some more text where the navigation list is more on the left side than in the first example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lsew6gg/3/

**Note**: Both have the same CSS styles defined:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 5em 0 0;
    right: 0%;
    top: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation div {
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#content div {
    width: 65% !important;
}
```

**Edit:**

As @Autista_z mentioned the navigation bar gets moved when there is a scrollbar but I don't want to always show a scrollbar. Isn't there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Becouse of scroll bar. It makes the viewport horizontally smaller

Comment: Sounds logical. Is there any good way to fix this? I'm not that familiar with front end development and don't want a *hacky* fix.

Comment: Can't see what you're trying to describe. Both links seem to be fine, with navigation staying fixed on right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said by @Autista_z it's just because of scrollbar.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/sck6nL6w/4/'
```

check this updates fiddle.

it's not fix but i want to show you how it's not an issue at all.

all i did is added this line of code

```
body {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This will always show both scrollbars what is not what I want. Isn't there another way?

Comment: i have updated the fiddle. check that again. use `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: Thanks for your effort but to always show a scrollbar (even if there is no need for it) isn't what I want. :/

Comment: you don't need to add that. what i meant is, the issue you posted is not an issue at all. just ignore it. it looks like shifting because of scrollbar. just ignore it

Comment: Sorry but it is a problem for me because I don't like it when a static navigation bar moves around.^^